# Camera won`t focus in a part

Tags: lua, roblox

I Have a bug, so script that focus camera doesn`t works in my game. But in roblox studio testing mode in works. It is Liocalscript located in StarterPlayerScripts.

That`s my script.

```
local cam = workspace.Camera
local cameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable


cam.CameraType = cameraType


repeat 
    cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
until cam.CameraType == Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
while wait() do
    cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    cam.CFrame = workspace.CameraPart.CFrame
end
```

I tried making not a LocalScript. Also pasting it in ServerScriptStorage, making it local and not local script.

Comment: Why are you using a repeat loop to set a variable?, and does `wait()` return true? i would venture a guess it returns nothing as such your code inside the while loop never gets called.

Comment: So can you please send your version of script, i really need help.

Comment: No, this is not a coding service. your example code above does the same thing on 3 lines, i would guess you are trying to do something that is currently beyond your skill level. I suggest you to take a step back learn the language, that you are trying to write code in, and look for tutorials.

Comment: Thnx, thats helpful

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will always want to run this locally, since the player is the only person that's going to have a camera in a real Roblox game.

I'm assuming that you want to control the camera of the playing user with as script. If that's true, you should only need to set the CameraType property once. There's no point in using a loop there. Once you set the camera type to Scriptable, you need to set the camera's CFrame to look at the part that you're targeting.

If I had a part in the workspace called "MyPart", then I could set the camera's CFrame to look in front of it. Where you set the CFrame is your choice. One way this can be accompished is setting the position of the camera 4 studs away from the part's LookVector and look at the part.

A pseudocode example of this is shown below:

```lua
local part = workspace.MyPart
local cam = workspace.CurrentCamera

-- Set camera type
cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable

-- Focus camera on part once
cam.CFrame = CFrame.new((part.CFrame + part.LookVector * 4).Position, part.Position)
```

If the part moved, however, you would have to compensate for that. If you plan on making the camera focus on the part dynamically, you will want to set the camera's CFrame on every frame, which can be done with RunService.RenderStepped.

Considering the fact that you're struggling a bit with the fundamentals of Roblox scripting, you may want to look a bit into Roblox's API reference and doing easier projects for the time being.

Comment: It didn`t help :(